# CakePHP 3 - Cookie

Tags: cakephp, cookies, cakephp-3.0

I have a problem when reading an associative array that's inside a cookie.

1. )

When I set it like this in the controller:

```
$this->set('info', $this->Cookie->read('info'));
```

I can read data this way in the view:

```
$info[0]['records'];
```

[ 'person_id' => 2, ...]

2. )

When I do this (because I read the cookie from a view cell):

```
$this->set('info', $this->request->cookie('info'));
```

I get the associative array as an string. (?) The whole array is an string:

'.''[{"person_id":2, ... "}]''.'

So, how can I 'avoid' this? Why does it become, via 'request', a String?

Edit:

In CakePHP, when you try to retrieve a cookie via 'request' (2.), you will normally get the hashed value of the cookie. When creating the cookie, I disabled the hashing. Maybe I didn't do that correctly.

Is it also possible to unhash it in a view cell?

Comment: `'.$info.'`? How is that a string representation of an array? Also how are you writing the cookie? Via the cookie component?

Comment: Sorry forgot one thing. In the display() method of the cell I set() the cookie to be able to show it in the display.ctp. When I debug($info) in display.ctp I get a String with the array printed.

Comment: Yes, I write it via the Cookie component. Hash disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there is a JSON string.

The Cookie component by default stores all data JSON encoded, and also encrypted (AES by default). Consequently it also decrypts and decodes the data when reading cookies.

When the cookie isn't encrypted, you could easily JSON decode it.

```
$decoded = json_decode($encoded, true);
```

If you were using encryption too, and/or you were unsure whether the value is JSON encoded or not, you could either use the Cookie component to decrypt/decode the cookies at controller level, like

```
$this->request->coookies['info'] = $this->Cookie->read('info');
```

or set it as a view variable that you can pass to your cell as an argument.

See also **[Cookbook > Views > View Cells > Passing Arguments to a Cell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html#passing-arguments-to-a-cell)**

As of CakePHP 3.1.7 you can also use the `\Cake\Utility\CookieCryptTrait` trait, which is used by the cookie component too. Just add it to your class, implement the `CookieCryptTrait::_getCookieEncryptionKey()` method to return the proper encryption key (by default the security salt), and use `CookieCryptTrait::_decrypt()` to unscramble the cookie data.

See also **[API > \Cake\Utility\CookieCryptTrait](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Utility.CookieCryptTrait.html)**

While this would work in a cell, the "problem" is that that the cell needs to know stuff from the outside world in order for this to work, it needs to know about the encryption key, and the encryption mode. Personally I'd probably use the former method, and if it would need to be the latter, pass the key and the mode to the cell as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the json_decode part. Will try it out soon. I got one extra question about passing arguments to a cell. I use the cell on the default template for creating a menu for all pages. I thought that here is no controller behind the default template? So how can I pass the parameter(s) to the view cell (in case I want the encryption too)?

Comment: @dnns Layout templates are wrapped around view templates, so whatever controller renders it, sits "before" it. If you want to set variables for the default layout, you'd use the app controller.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it, including the encryption.